# I want my JTable at the centre

Tags: java, jtable

I want my JTable at the centre of my JFrame and for this purpose i have used setbounds method but it's not doing anything and i don't want to use layout managers.I just want to know that why it's not doing anything?
Here is my code:

```
   tabel=new JTable(data,columnNames);
   tabel.setLayout(null);
   tabel.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
   tabel.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
   JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane(tabel);
   pane.setBounds(100,700,200,200);
  add(pane);
```

Comment: You may want to use GridBagLayout.You definitely should not place your components over null layout.

Comment: without using Gridbaglayout i can't do anything?

Comment: Your code doesn't help to solve the problem at all. OK, it shows that you doesn't care about patterns and set Layout to null.

Comment: What is stopping you from using a layout manager?

Comment: @xenteros i want  jtable at the centre by using setting layout to null.Can you provide me some information regarding this because ass you can see that i have used setbounds method but it's not doing anything, why?

Comment: @AnkitTripathi ok then show me how can i move jtable at the centre by using gridbaglayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use layout managers but if you insist,that you want to move JTable in JFrame by setting layout to null,then you should try the following option:
(1)Make a JPanel in JFrame and add that table to JPanel in this way

```
 JPanel panel=new JPanel();
   panel.setBounds(20,300,700,300);
   add(panel);
   tabel=new JTable(data,columnNames);
   tabel.setBounds(100,20,700,400);
   tabel.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
   tabel.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
   JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane(tabel);
   panel.add(pane);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add everything to a JPanel, and then set the layout of the JPanel to a border layout. Add the table to the JPanel and then position it at the center. This is the easiest way to do it. Layouts may seem complicated and inconvenient at first but once you learn them, you quickly realise they are a million times easier that setting bounds and null layouts. Here is a link to learn about border layout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Answer (score 0):

You are adding JTable to a JFrame(Top level component).This may get you going

```
JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints layout= new GridBagConstraints();
JTable jtable = new JTable();
jtable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
jtable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
layout.weightx = 1;
layout.weighty = 1;
layout.gridx = 0;
layout.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(jtable), layout)
```

You may want to set layout dimensions and insets according to your jtable.